# Question about integral is equal to zero

Tags: calculus, integration, integral-equations

Suppose we have the following equation
$$
\int_0^\infty  {f(x,r)g(x)dx}  = 0 \quad {\rm for \, all}\, r\in \mathbb{R}
$$
where the function $g(x)$ does not depend on $r$, while $f(x,r)$ is function of $x$ and $r$. Can I conclude that $g(x)= 0$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: You need to be more precise. Is this condition true for any $f$ or a specific $f$. If it is not a specific $f$ what role does $r$ play? Also, are there any continuity conditions?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. My function $f$ is quite complicated $f(x,r) = e^{-x-r^2/2}I_0(\sqrt{2x}r)$ where $I_0(y) \triangleq \int_0^\pi  {e^{y\cos(t)}dt}$ is the Bessel function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessarily.  Thus take any $g \in L^2[0,\infty)$.  The orthogonal complement of $g$ is a closed subspace $V$ of $L^2[0,\infty)$ of codimension $1$, and you could take any $f$ so that $f(.,r) \in V$ for all $r$.   Examples are very easy to construct.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what $f$ is. In general, problems of the form "find $g$ given $h(r) = \int_a^b f(x,r) g(r) dr$ are known as [Fredholm integral equations of the first kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FredholmIntegralEquationoftheFirstKind.html) and are typically not fun.

For example, if $f$ is zero, then $g$ could be anything.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out Fredholm integral equations of the first kind.

Comment: $f$ is quite complicated $f(x,r) = e^{-x-r^2/2}I_0(\sqrt{2x}r)$ where $I_0(y) \triangleq \int_0^\pi  {e^{y\cos(t)}dt}$ is the Bessel function.